# asp.net c# detailview how to set column width

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with setting column width to the detailview. Tried different options like headerstyle with and fieldstyle width. But none of them seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use **FieldHeaderStyle-Width="400px"** to control the width of first i.e. heading column.

Answer (score 1):

Plz Try it.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="C_id" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
        ForeColor="Blue" Height="100px" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Red" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="Blue" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" Width="40%"/>
```

Comment: This is making entire detail view 100% width. But not columns 40%

Comment: <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"
AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
Height="50px" Width="800px" FieldHeaderStyle-Width="400px">